# Cannot solve error message Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, where-clause

I cannot figure out why I keep getting errors everything looks fine:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

```
SELECT [BFName] 
      ,[S]
      ,[D]
      ,[T]
      ,[N]
, [WeeklyAverage]
, [4WeekAverage]
, [Range] 
  FROM [dbReportCard].[dbo].[vw_Bullfrog_WER_Modified_Frequency_Crosstab_with_Totals]
   where [ProductionWeek] = '[cb#ProductionWeek]'
   and [BFName] = 'BF 16'
```

Comment: I do not think "[cb#ProductionWeek]" is a good attendee value for a ProductionWeek !

Comment: I totally agree but my boss wants to keep it for some reason

Answer (score 1):

This error would probably come from the `where` clause:

```
where [ProductionWeek] = '[cb#ProductionWeek]'
```

Presumably, `ProductionWeek` is of a date-like datatype. Presumably, you want to compare it against *column* `cb#ProductionWeek`, which would also be a date or the-like. *But* the single quotes around the column name turn it to a literal string, which SQL Server then tries to convert to a date for comparison - which, of course, fails.

I suspect that you just want:

```
where [ProductionWeek] = [cb#ProductionWeek]
```

Comment: If this really is the case, isn't this simply a typographical error?

Comment: @Larnu: I thought it was worth an explanation, hence the answer, that could have start with: "This is too long for a comment"...

Comment: I wish it were that simple. But cb#ProductionWeek is not a table, so it will not query without them.

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
This is the error. So I agree that it is date being represented as astring.

Comment: @GMcRae: so, maybe `where [ProductionWeek] = convert(date, [cb#ProductionWeek])` - or `where [ProductionWeek] = convert(datetime, [cb#ProductionWeek])`